# Hibernate inner join and group by difficulty

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, join, group-by

I'd like to fetch the most commented articles.  How do I do this?

MySQL does not support the following syntax, but basically I'm looking to do something like:

> SELECT * FROM Article WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM Comment GROUP BY
>   article_id ORDER BY article_id DESC LIMIT 10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could look like this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   Article AS a
JOIN  (
    SELECT article_id
    FROM   Comment
    GROUP  BY article_id
    ORDER  BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT  10
    ) AS c ON c.article_id = a.id;
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works well in MySQL.  Now I just have ot figure out how to do it with Hibernate :-)

Comment: Looks like simply running createNativeQuery will work.  Thanks again.